# Hibernate Mapping Issue with postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I am trying to map the following entity but getting hibernate mapping exception. Help will be much appreciated.
Remember, Iam using PostgreSQL

```
package st.malike.auth.server.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2RefreshToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;


@Entity
public class OAuth2AuthenticationRefreshToken implements Serializable {

//    @Indexed
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    private final String tokenId;
    private final OAuth2RefreshToken oAuth2RefreshToken;
    private final OAuth2Authentication authentication;

    public OAuth2AuthenticationRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken oAuth2RefreshToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        this.oAuth2RefreshToken = oAuth2RefreshToken;
        this.authentication = authentication;
        this.tokenId = oAuth2RefreshToken.getValue();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTokenId() {
        return tokenId;
    }

    public OAuth2RefreshToken getoAuth2RefreshToken() {
        return oAuth2RefreshToken;
    }

    public OAuth2Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

And getting exception as below

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2RefreshToken, 
  at table: oauth2authentication_refresh_token, 
  for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(o_auth2refresh_token)]     
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:369) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    ... 162 common frames omitted
```

Comment: please provide the schema of your table too

Comment: Do you intend to store the value of all your fields into your database? especially the fields `oAuth2RefreshToken` and `authentication`, do you want them to be stored into the db? if not annotate them with `@Transient` or add the modifier `transient` to their declaration

Comment: @Zulfi  configuration is spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/eCoreAS
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgre
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.maxActive=10
spring.datasource.maxIdle=5
spring.datasource.minIdle=2
spring.datasource.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

Comment: If you do want to store `OAuth2AuthenticationRefreshToken`, and `OAuth2Authentication` in your DB, you need to specify the mapping to hibernate (to which other hibernate entity it is linked). Is that what you intend to do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not saving any value for the attribute `oAuth2RefreshToken`, then add the annotation `@Transient` to ignore any mapping with the database.

If you have some mapping, please add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

Change interface `OAuth2RefreshToken (OAuth2AccessToken)` into `DefaultOAuth2RefreshToken (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken)` in your `Entity` class. `DefaultOAuth2RefreshToken (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken)` are class but not interface. Postgres BD will save it as `BYTEA`.

Finally, I invite you to read this Hibernate Link in order to know the POJO Model which can use that **Entity Model** in
Hibernate https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer to also explain why (your reasoning) OP should make your proposed changes. In this way your answer becomes much more helpful for future readers. Also refer to the [contribution guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).